# Unable to determine why the space appears in buttons in angular2 html

Tags: html, css, angular, button

Initially my page appears like this, with one input text box and a "+" button and a "-" button. 
Image -

[image: Initial Image]

Now, if i click on the "+" button , the size between the first text-box and button increases. Please have a look -

Image -

[image: After "+" click, image]

Please guide on why such a gap appears. This gap doesn't appear when i click on subsequent "+" buttons.

code -

**app.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="addContainer">
  <p style="margin-left: 200px; font-size:18px">Please enter the node -</p>

  <table align="center">

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input *ngIf="addMore" type="text" placeholder="Enter a Node" value="Aadhar">
              </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" style="margin-left: 10px" (click)="addOneMore()" class="btn btn-success"> + </button>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" style="margin-left: 10px" class="btn btn-danger"> - </button>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr *ngFor="let container of containers" >
             <div #myElement>
            <td >
              <input *ngIf="addMore" type="text" placeholder="Enter a Node" value="Aadhar">
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" style="margin-left: 10px" (click)="addOneMore()" class="btn btn-success"> + </button>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" style="margin-left: 10px" (click)="myElement.remove()" class="btn btn-danger"> - </button>
            </td>
          </div>
          </tr>


      <tr>

        <td style="text-align:center">
          <button type="button" (click)="showGraphs()" class="btn btn-dark">Search</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: is there any error in console?

Comment: @Sarthak .. No error in console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because of extra `div` inside the `tr`. replace the `div` by `ng-container`.

```
  <tr *ngFor="let container of containers" >
         <ng-container #myElement>
        <td >
          <input *ngIf="addMore" type="text" placeholder="Enter a Node" value="Aadhar">
        </td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" style="margin-left: 10px" (click)="addOneMore()" class="btn btn-success"> + </button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" style="margin-left: 10px" (click)="myElement.remove()" class="btn btn-danger"> - </button>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
      </tr>
```

### OR

> you can put the reference myElement at tr level

```
 <tr *ngFor="let container of containers" #myElement >
         <ng-container >
        <td >
          <input *ngIf="addMore" type="text" placeholder="Enter a Node" value="Aadhar">
        </td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" style="margin-left: 10px" (click)="addOneMore()" class="btn btn-success"> + </button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" style="margin-left: 10px" (click)="myElement.remove()" class="btn btn-danger"> - </button>
        </td>

      </tr>
```

Comment: But i am unable to implement the logic of the div . WHat to do ?

Comment: Hi Sunil, can you please help me  -  here with every iteration , a new text box will appear, how to gather so many [(ngModel)] of every text box value

Comment: You already have the an array `containers` and you iterating over it. If you have any property in the container you want to bind then it would be pretty easy as  `<input *ngIf="addMore"  [(ngModel)] ="container.adhar" type="text" placeholder="Enter a Node" value="Aadhar">`

Answer (score 1):

I did this -

**app.component.ts**

```
   deleteOneMore(){

    this.containers.splice(this.index, 1);
    }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let container of containers; let i = index;" >
          <ng-container >
            <td  >
              <input *ngIf="addMore" type="text" placeholder="Enter a Node" value="Aadhar">
            </td>
            <td  >
              <button type="button" style="margin-left: 10px" (click)="addOneMore()" class="btn btn-success"> + </button>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" style="margin-left: 10px" (click)="deleteOneMore()" class="btn btn-danger"> - </button>
            </td>
          </ng-container>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is my answer i think it will help you with your problem, you have used a class in every button called "btn" and it contain by default padding of padding: .375rem .75rem; so you guess my answer, you have to remove it and you will be fine.
[when padding were not removed from btn class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pR4yv.png) 
[when padding removed from btn class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bu49m.png)[just checked after commenting this btn padding in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4vTM.png)